# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{^5x-^4x}{(1-x)^5}$, where $^nx$ is the repeated exponent ("tetration") operation

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}-{x^{x^{x^x}}}}{(1-x)^5}$$

My friends told that it appeared on Instagram (some social media network). I tried various methods but failed. (I tried using Taylor series but failed. Tried l'Hopital but failed. Tried substitution but failed. Gave up here.) They also said that some of the comments claim that the answer is $\;-1.$

Comment: What various methods did you try?

Comment: The limit is correct.

Comment: I tried using Taylor series but failed. Tried l'hoptital but failed. Tried substitution but failed. Gave up here. @saulspatz

Comment: How to solve it? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: It seems like l"Hopital should work, although it might be tedious.  What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f_0(x)=1$, $f_n(x) = x^{x^{x^{\cdots^{x}}}}=\, ^nx$ be $n$ iterated exponent. We can see
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f_1(x)-f_0(x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1.
\end{eqnarray}$$ If we define $F(t,x)=t^x =e^{x\log t}$, we can see by mean value theorem that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
F(x,f_n(x))-F(x,f_{n-1}(x))&=&F_2\left(x,s_xf_n(x)+(1-s_x)f_{n-1}(x)\right)(f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x))
\end{eqnarray}$$ for some $s_x\in (0,1)$. Assume $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}=a_n$$ exists. Then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x)}{(x-1)^{n+1}}&=&\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{F(x,f_n(x))-F(x,f_{n-1}(x))}{(x-1)^{n+1}}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{F_2\left(x,s_xf_n(x)+(1-s_x)f_{n-1}(x)\right)(f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x))}{(x-1)^{n+1}}\\&=&a_n\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{F_2\left(x,s_xf_n(x)+(1-s_x)f_{n-1}(x)\right)}{x-1}\\&=&a_n\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\log x\cdot x^{s_xf_n(x)+(1-s_x)f_{n-1}(x)}}{x-1}\\
&=&a_n.
\end{eqnarray}$$ By induction, it follows that $a_{n+1}=a_n =\cdots =a_1 =1$. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}-{x^{x^{x^x}}}}{(1-x)^5}=-a_5=-1.
$$

Comment: Nice use of induction, for sure ! $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 4):

Start using composition of Taylor series using mainly $t=e^{\log(t)}$. Then
$$x^x=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{1}{3} (x-1)^4+\frac{1}{12}
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$
$$x^{x^x}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{4}{3} (x-1)^4+\frac{3}{2}
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$
$$x^{x^{x^x}}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{7}{3} (x-1)^4+3
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$
$$x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{7}{3} (x-1)^4+4
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$ Which shows the limit.

If you continue the expansion, you would get
$$\frac{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}-x^{x^{x^x}}}{(1-x)^5}=-1-2 (x-1)-\frac{13}{3} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$

Use your computer with $x=1.1$. The "exact" value would be $\approx -1.2525$ while the above expansion gives $-\frac{373}{300}\approx -1.2433$.