# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{x^{x^{{x}^{x}}}}-x^{x^{x^x}}}{(x-1)^5}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Question:Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{x^{x^{{x}^{x}}}}-x^{x^{x^x}}}{(x-1)^5}$.

This is $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminant form. If we use L-Hopital's rule the calculations become a bit lengthy.Tried to make some substitutions too, but didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: What substitutions did you make?

Comment: Like $(x-1)=h^{1/5}$, complexified even more!

Comment: Is the answer 1?

Comment: I think so @JaiSriKrishna. Mathematica and fivefold use of l'Hospital suggests that. But won't satisfy me :-)

Comment: I plotted the graph in Desmos, which helped me finding the limit, But I think ourselves plotting the graph would be difficult :(

Comment: yes ;) @JaiSriKrishna

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083187/evaluating-lim-x-to-1-frac5x-4x1-x5-where-nx-is-the-repeated-e?noredirect=1

Comment: yes @Cathedral, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The problem of
$$f_n=x^{(n+1)}-x^{(n)}$$ around $x=1$ is simple if you start letting $x=1+y$ and have the patience of building the series expansion around $y=0$.

$$f_1=y^2+\frac{y^3}{2}+O\left(y^4\right)$$
$$f_2=y^3+y^4+O\left(y^5\right)$$

Comment: You also answered the duplicate in 2019. I would think this limit is  unusual enough that it would ring a bell.

Answer (score 3):

Numerator = $\displaystyle x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} -x^{x^{x^{x}}} = [1+(x-1)]^{x^{x^{x^x}}} - [1+(x-1)]^{x^{x^{x}}} \approx (x-1) [x^{x^{x^x}}-x^{x^{x}}]\approx (x-1)^2[x^{x^{x}}-x^{x}]$

$\approx (x-1)^3[x^x-x] \approx (x-1)^5$

Edit: The approximation used is $(1+x)^r \approx 1+rx$ for small values of $x$ as a first approximation.

Comment: posted around the same time as Claude Leibovici. Will leave it here if it is useful to OP.

Comment: Please mention some info about the approximation that you have used.